# How to add full width background in two column (col-md-6) on bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I would like to ask how to add full width background on two column (col-md-6) in bootstrap 3. Please refer to the image.

As you can see in the image there are two column the **green background** and the **image**. How to set full width background on each column?

Thanks for the help :)

[image: bootstrap container size 1170px with two column md 6]

```html
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row"> 
      <div class="col-md-6 the-green-bg"> 
        <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> 
        <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip </p> 
        <a href="#">Learn more</a> 
              
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-6"> 
        <!-- full-width image --> 
        </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: add some html & css code you try

Comment: could you share your HTML structure and what you have tried ? the row is a full-width row or a boxed-row ?

Comment: here's my html structure:

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 the-green-bg">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
      <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip </p>
      <a href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <!-- full-width image -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: Have you tried using `container-fluid` instead of `container`?

Comment: check my answer below. let me know if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/31642/) or snippet below ( but better see fiddle because you use `col-md` and you need to see the result in a larger area )

the second `col-md-6` can't have a background-image because it doesn't a content in it and so it doesn't have a height to fill with background-image.

the trick is to set **`display:flex`** on the `row` so that the cols have equal height.

if you want the row to be full page width. use `container-fluid` instead of `container`

let me know if it helps

```css
.row {
 display:flex;
}
.row .col-md-6{
 padding:30px 15px;
}
.row {
 background:green;
}
.row .col-md-6{
 background-image:url("http://placehold.it/350x150");
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid"> 
  <div class="row"> 
     <div class="col-md-2"> 
   </div>
      <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> 
        <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip </p> 
        <a href="#">Learn more</a> 
              
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-6"> 
        <!-- full-width image --> 
        </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: No luck, It only covers inside the col-md-6 not outside of the column

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks. Please check this link: https://www.templatemonster.com/demo/61344.html under the Our Services section there are two columns. That what's look like I want to achieve.

Comment: the row that is under OUR services is just like the first solution i gave you. i write another solution now. check it out in the answer or here > https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/31642/

Comment: The solution that you gave are only render inside the row column 6. Still did not work on full width

Comment: hmm..it's full width. check your other css . `container-fluid` means full width . and instead of the first `col-md-6` i made a `col-md-2 and col-md-4` so the text is not right near the left side of the row.

Comment: Yes! Finally I got it. Container-fluid works and I follow your revise code in jsfiddle.net for the image. Now it looks awesome! Thank you very much for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
 .padding_remove {
   padding: 0px;
 }
 .bg-green {
  background-color: green;
 }
 .bg-black {
  background-color: black;
 }
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 padding_remove">
   <div class="col-md-6 bg-green">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6 bg-black">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/mike1234-pixel/pen/ExwYyOb

The only way I could create something like this was by using javascript. see the codepen link above. the width and padding are anchored to a bootstrap standard container / columns at the top.

The downside to this solution is using js for layout purposes which is not ideal. However, achieving this layout on the design doesn't seem to be possible with css alone... I haven't found a solution to this on stack overflow myself.

The challenge here is having the inner edge of the columns align with a standard bootstrap container, which is of variable width, and having the padding on the outer edges of those columns align with the edge of a standard container.

```
 <html>
     <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      </head>
      <body>
        <section>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="topcol1 col-12 col-sm-6">
                <p>col1</p>
              </div>
              <div class="topcol2 col-12 col-sm-6">
                <p>col2</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="overflow-row">
              <div class="column1">
                <p>col1</p>
              </div>
              <div class="column2">
                <p>col2</p>  
               </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    
    <style>
    .overflow-row {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      @media (max-width: 576px) {
        flex-direction: column;
      }
    }
    
    .topcol1 {
    background: yellow;
    }
    
    .topcol2 {
    background: orange;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    
    .column1 {
      background: red;
      
    }
    
    .column2 {
      background: green;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
    }
        
    </style>
    <script>
    let position = $('.topcol1').offset();
    let padding = position.left + 24;
    
    let column1width = $('.topcol1').width() + position.left + 24;
    let column2width = $('.topcol2').width() + position.left + 24;
    
    function addColumnPadding() {
      // these vars need recalculating/reassigning on resize
      position = $('.topcol1').offset();
      padding = position.left + 12;
      $('.column1').css('padding-left', padding)
      $('.column2').css('padding-right', padding)
    }
    
    function adjustColumnWidth() {
      column1width = $('.topcol1').width() + position.left + 24;
      column2width = $('.topcol2').width() + position.left + 24;
      $('.column1').css('width', column1width);
      $('.column2').css('width', column2width);
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
      addColumnPadding();
      adjustColumnWidth();
    })
    
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
      addColumnPadding();
      adjustColumnWidth();
    })
    </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A flex box method would work here

https://codepen.io/nitrokev/pen/abqOoEr

```
.article-container{
max-width:1200px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
section{
margin-bottom:2rem;}

.article-grid{
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
justify-content: center;
align-items: stretch;
}
article{
flex:1 50%;
display: flex;
font-family: arial;
 }
article:nth-of-type(1){
background-color:blue;
color:white;
justify-content: flex-end;
}
article:nth-of-type(2){
background-color:red;
color:white;
justify-content: flex-start;
}

.article-inner-grid{
max-width: 600px;
}
.article-padding{
padding:2rem;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).